# Append not populating target dataset - Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, field-mapping, append

I am attempting to append several features from an input dataset to a target dataset.  Both datasets have several matching fields, which are the ones that I would like to keep - fields that do not match do not need to be kept.  I was under the impression that if "NO_TEST" is used in the append tool, the schemas do not have to match and all matching fields will populate without specifying fieldmappings.  However, when I run my script, the input data is not populating the target dataset.  Here is my code:

```
layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(sgcnpolygons, "sgcn_lyr")
selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer, "NEW_SELECTION", '"Environment" = \'a\'')
tempCatchments = arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(catchments, selection, "in_memory\\tempCatchments", "", "KEEP_COMMON")
sgcn = arcpy.Append_management(tempCatchments, sgcnpolygons, "NO_TEST")
```

Comment: Perhaps the Select by Attribute is not selecting anything. You can add a GetCount after the selection.

Comment: I have confirmed that my tempCatchments layer is populated with features.